# Why "systemd[1]: user@65534.service: Killing process"

Tags: debian, systemd

Some server I recently upgraded to Debian 9 now produce a strange syslog message every day (which got reported via logcheck):

```
Oct 27 06:25:08 foo systemd[1]: user@65534.service: Killing process 12270 (kill) with signal SIGKILL.
```

The time seems to be that of cron.daily and the name of the service looks like the UID of nobody/nogroup but why has it to die and what was it doing in the first place?

More syslog lines around that time. That block repeats a couple of times:

```
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of nobody.
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 65534...
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[1]: Started Session 1377 of user nobody.
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[12264]: Reached target Paths.
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[12264]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (access for web browsers).
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[12264]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[12264]: Reached target Timers.
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[12264]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[12264]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[12264]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[12264]: Reached target Sockets.
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[12264]: Reached target Basic System.
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[12264]: Reached target Default.
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[12264]: Startup finished in 12ms.
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 65534.
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 65534...
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[12264]: Stopped target Default.
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[12264]: Stopped target Basic System.
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[12264]: Stopped target Sockets.
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[12264]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[12264]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[12264]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (access for web browsers).
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[12264]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[12264]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[12264]: Reached target Shutdown.
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[12264]: Starting Exit the Session...
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[12264]: Stopped target Timers.
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[12264]: Stopped target Paths.
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[12264]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 12270 (kill).
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[1]: user@65534.service: Killing process 12270 (kill) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 65534.
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of nobody.
Oct 27 06:25:08 svn systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of nobody.
```

The PID 12264 has no further entries in syslog/syslog.1.

Comment: `egrep -R nobody /etc/cron.*/` My 1.  thought was popularity-contest

Comment: No PopCon installed. The egrep only lists /etc/cron.daily/locate which gives no errors on execution.

Comment: [This bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83100) sounds related.